# Many to Many relationship not working

Tags: breeze

I have two junction/bridge tables, DailyLogEmployees and DailyLogVendors to handle a many to many relationship:

```
public class DailyLog:ActiveEntity
{
   public int Id {get;set;}
    [ForeignKey("EmployeeId")]
    public ICollection<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("VendorId")]
    public ICollection<Vendor> Vendors { get; set; }
}
and defined in the model as such
modelBuilder.Entity<DailyLog>().HasMany(d => d.Employees).WithMany().Map(m =>
    {                                                                                                    m.MapLeftKey("DailyLogId");
                                                                                      m.MapRightKey("EmployeeId");
                                                                                      m.ToTable("DailyLogEmployees");
                                                                                  });
modelBuilder.Entity<DailyLog>().HasMany(d => d.Vendors).WithMany().Map(m =>
  {                                                                                            m.MapLeftKey("DailyLogId");
                                                                                          m.MapRightKey("VendorId");
                                                                                          m.ToTable(
                                                                                              "DailyLogVendors");
                                                                                        });
```

The items are created in the metadata, however when I instantiate a new DailyLog, neither Employees or Vendors are present.

Breeze is version 1.3.6 am I doing something stupid, I don't want any navigation on the other side, Employees or Vendors just on the DailyLog any help or insight is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Breeze does not YET support many-many relations.  For the time being you can expose these as two 1-many relations... and please add your vote to our [User-Voice](https://breezejs.uservoice.com/forums/173093-breeze-feature-suggestions) on this topic.